# Does Microsoft Power Point 2013 have auto-connect?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-visio

This is the same feature as in Visio where you can rapidly connect a bunch of shapes already on the page, as opposed to clicking the connector tool each time to link two shapes.

Does PP have it?  If so, where is it?

Comment: Don't even think about having such feature in any other MS product other than Visio. Drawing is a pain when it comes to MS applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it does.
1) select connector
2) make your first connector
3) right-click connector button, in tool bar
4) select drawing mode

Now you can connect shape to shape to shape by just click and drag from shape to shape,

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it definitely doesn't. The best you can do is select a connector type over and over again. [This tutorial](http://www.indezine.com/products/powerpoint/learn/shapes/types-of-connectors-in-ppt2011-mac.html) may be a little helpful even though its a different version.

Since PP is pretty terrible at making connections look good, I often make one or two and then copy them however many times I'll need and move them around. It's the quickest way to get to a decent diagram.